# Sql server 2005 knowing new record is inserted

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any way to find out whether a new record is inserted other than writing trigger in sql server 2005. (it can be tsql or by java...)
Since the vendor is not allowing to right trigger on there DB...
Also how to generate a file with data of newly inserted row.. is bcp a good solution??

Comment: a timestamp is not enough? Or a flag: `new_from_last_check bit default 0`

Answer (score 1):

You can define an audit table and then add an OUTPUT command to your INPUT or UPDATE statements (DELETE's too, btw).

```
create table fab4 (id int identity(1,1),FName varchar(80));
create table fab4_audit (act varchar(10),id int, FName_old varchar(80), FName_new varchar(80), ts datetime not null default(getdate()));

-- insert
insert into fab4(FName)
output
'INSERTED'
, inserted.*
into fab4_audit([act],id,FName_new)
select 'John' union all
select 'Paul' union all
select 'George' union all
select 'Ringo';
go

-- update
update f
set FName='Walrus'
output
'UPDATED'
, inserted.id
, deleted.FName
, inserted.FName
into fab4_audit([act],id,FName_old,FName_new)
from fab4 f
where FName='Paul';

-- delete
delete f
output
'DELETED'
, deleted.id
, deleted.FName
into fab4_audit([act],id,FName_old)
from fab4 f
where FName in ('John','George');
go

select * from fab4;
select * from fab4_audit;
go
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a best practice that might also help you out here.  If you restrict updates and inserts to only go through a stored procedure, you could use that proc to also write out either an audit record or simply update a time/date field.

Answer (score 0):

Does the table have an auto increment primary key or a createDate column?  You could write your a cron job that wakes up periodically and queries to see if anything new has hit the database since you last time you ran the cron job.

Comment: CDC will help?? I am getting links and tutorial in 2008 but i am using sql server 2005....

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define "Is there any way to find out whether a new record is inserted other than writing trigger".  Triggers are basically event handlers in SQL.  So are you wanting to have something like a trigger that fires whenever a new row is inserted into a table?  If so, the answer is yes, it's called SQL Server Notification Services.

Here's a [beginners article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2835/An-Introduction-to-SQL-Server-Notification-Service), but I'm sure you can just google "sql server notification" and get tons of results.

Here's another good article: [Using SqlDependency To Monitor SQL Database Changes](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/156991-using-sqldependency-to-monitor-sql-database-changes/)

Comment: CDC will help?? I am getting links and tutorial in 2008 but i am using sql server 2005.

Comment: Here's one for SqlDependency for 2005 / VS2005. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12335/Using-SqlDependency-for-data-change-events