# Non-destructive updates, versioning finance data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-design

I have three tables (lots in reality but these three are the ones I have to worry about right now)

A product line table like...

```
ProductLineId (pk)
Name
Description
Price
Finance Event (FK)
```

and a finance event table like...

```
EventId (pk)
Event Description
```

and a Financial Transaction table like...

```
TransactionId (pk)
FinanceEventId (fk)
LotsOfSageReferencesAndOtherForeignKeys
```

When a sale is processed it creates transaction records based on the Finance Events etc.

The question is; if someone in the admin then goes in and changes the Finance event what is the best way of versioning the events table, while preserving the primary key.

Comment: Don't let finance events be changed. Put an `IsActive` field on finance event, and when people want to "change an event", make it so that the old one is deactivated and a new one created. Finance-y people will understand the importance of maintaining an audit.

Comment: I've already added an Archived BIT to it, and killed the auto-increment. Technically the transactions table would need to know which of the, possibly many, versions of that data it was created based on.

Comment: You could create a audit table and maintain it through either DML triggers or by adding the `OUTPUT` directive to your DML statements. I gave an `OUTPUT` example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243389/sql-server-2005-knowing-new-record-is-inserted/9247000#9247000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you have several choices:

First when dealing with temporal data, you should store the actual values not just the ids in the transaction table. Then the other tables serve as lookup tables for the creation of new records, but you always know what the real data was at the time of the transactions, This would include things that change over time like price, customer name, etc. Note you may also need to store the id field in case you need to look up what the current equivalent is.

Or you can disallow updates entirely on your lookup tables and through a trigger, deactivate the current record and insert a new one when someone runs an update statement. Now your child tables hold the values of the record that was active at the time the record was created.  What you lose in this scenario is the ability to look up what the current value would be (which is why you might not want to do it for something like customer name or price).

For data where you might not care if it changed over time, but would want to reflect the current information, allow the updates but have an audit or history table maintained through triggers; so you can recreate what the value would have been at the time if you need to, or to see who changed what and when (sometimes a legal requirement).

Which of these options suits your current situation, only you would know.