# SQL server determine which row was inserted?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a sql query which inserts a lot of new rows in table and updates a lot of old rows.
Is there a way to determine all rows which where inserted?

Comment: All rows that exist in the table were technically inserted.  You need to specify criteria for us to work with.

Comment: @Jeff: The updated rows are also added to the deleted table before they are added to the inserted table. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214435%28v=sql.80%29.aspx Maybe that'll help to distinguish between both.

Comment: See [Sql server 2005 knowing new record is inserted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243389/sql-server-2005-knowing-new-record-is-inserted/9247000#9247000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this in a previous Stackoverflow article:
[How to insert multiple records and get the identity value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95988/how-to-insert-multiple-records-and-get-the-identity-value)

Below is by Andy Irving:

Use the ouput clause from 2005:

```
DECLARE @output TABLE (id int)

Insert into A (fname, lname)
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @output
SELECT fname, lname FROM B

select * from @output
```

now your table variable has the identity values of all the rows you insert.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you try something like execute

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

after execute INSERT statement?

Take a look at [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 0):

@@IDENTITY is deprecated, You would be recommended to use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

You can also determine the inserted items via the inserted table